# What does numbers mean in `mkfs -t ext4` command?

Tags: linux, formatting, ext4

I have run:

```
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/nvme0n1
```

So I am getting output like that:

```
[2491.001727] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[2491.543355] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[2491.702837] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

What does `2491.702837` mean? HOw to determine the rest of process from such log?

Answer (score 3):

The message is **not related to your mkfs command.** (And it talks about a different device, too.)

Console messages starting with `[number.number]` are usually shown by the kernel. (The number is a monotonic timestamp; number of seconds since boot.) You can see the full kernel log by running `dmesg -H` or `journalctl -k`, which will also decode the timestamp.

This specific message is shown by the ext4 filesystem driver regarding `/dev/dm-3` (a virtual device created by device-mapper; possibly a LUKS container or a LVM volume), and it means that someone successfully ran the `mount` command (or did the equivalent syscall).